# How to access microsoft graph if I already have Acces and Authorization Token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an Access Token for Microsoft Graph and the Authorization Token of the user. These are passed from the Client to the API with every request in the Headers. The Access token comes from reading the AccessToken to access Microsoft Graph on the SPA Client.

This is my Authentication implementation in my Startup.cs class.

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

I would like to write a helper class with an Interface that I can call every request to call the Microsoft Graph Api with my Access and/or Authorization Token and read the contents of the response from "https://graph.microsoft.com/me/memberOf". Both the SPA Client Application and API are registered in Azure AD and have the  **Member.Read.Hidden** Granted by the admin.

All the implementations that I have found online require you to Authenticate the user and get an Access token before calling the Graph.